# Unexpected string in JSON on npm install for existing module

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, reactjs, npm

I did an `npm update` a few hours back and now it seems like I can't do `npm install` anymore. Every time I do that, I get the error

`Unexpected string in JSON on npm install for existing module`

My logs seem to indicate that it is in the module `bluebird` as can be seen here:

`13 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 493
13 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
13 verbose stack     at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/parse-json.js:3:15)
13 verbose stack     at BB.join (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/read-shrinkwrap.js:31:20)
13 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
13 verbose stack     at Holder$3._callFunction (eval at generateHolderClass (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/join.js:92:16), <anonymous>:14:44)
13 verbose stack     at Holder$3.checkFulfillment (eval at generateHolderClass (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/join.js:92:16), <anonymous>:29:30)
13 verbose stack     at Promise.eval (eval at thenCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/join.js:14:16), <anonymous>:6:20)
13 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:566:21)
13 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
13 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
13 verbose stack     at Promise._fulfill (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:638:18)
13 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:582:21)
13 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
13 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
13 verbose stack     at Promise._fulfill (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:638:18)
13 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/nodeback.js:42:21
14 verbose cwd /Users/
15 verbose Darwin 17.3.0
16 verbose argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/8.9.1/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
17 verbose node v8.9.1
18 verbose npm  v5.5.1
19 error Unexpected string in JSON at position 493
20 verbose exit [ 1, true ]`

So it clearly seems like the issue is inside `bluebird`. I tried updating it but it didn't help and it seems like the only way is to delete the local copy. It seems to be a dependency for `babel` so I don't think to delete it is the right way. Is there another way to fix this issue?

**EDIT** So I deleted the local copy of bluebird from my system by using `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird` but when I tried to install it again using `npm install bluebird` I get an error that `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` `Cannot find module bluebird`

Comment: how about rm -rf node-modules/ && npm install

Comment: @LivingThing it's throwing the same error